# Bluetooth-Android ICS Base build 

Tags: android

I build android ICS base software for emulator. This builds ok.
Then, I have modified the c files in the path: “external\bluetooth\bluez\attrib\gattrip.c.”  Also other c files in this location. I am not sure how do I build this file on ICS base.

Before I build I build for Emulator successfully I have used the commands as shown below:

source build/envsetup.sh
lunch full-eng
make –j4

Do I need to build NDK build for these files, if yes how do I do this?
Also could you kindly let me know how do I build this c files and how do I check this has been build successfully.

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could compile them by building your whole Android again. Or you could try to cross compile the pieces by hand. But I would go for a whole rebuild.

Go to the dir where you've cloned the git and run this:

```
. build/envsetup.sh && lunch full-eng && make –j4
```

If you were able to build the rom for the emulator you should be able to build it again.

Comment: Hi I have done this way but it did not pull the C files that I modified. The reason why I am saying is I purposely put some information so that I can get error but it did not throw and error.

Comment: But do you know for sure It's even using these files? You can check this inside of the Makefile and Android.mk file inside the directory of your C files that you've modified.

Comment: I did check this on my android.mk file . The"gattrip.c” has been included. i also create new file and included in the make file. the c files i modified in the following path path: “external\bluetooth\bluez\attrib\gattrip.c.”